# Change Angular Theme through RouterOutlet

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I got the problem that I have a separate setting component which should be able to change the theme. But because it's called in the router-outlet it has no effect. If I do it through the header that is a clear child of app-component it works.

app-component.html

```html
 <div [ngClass]="{'dark-theme': isDarkTheme | async}">
   <div class="mat-app-background">
     <app-header></app-header>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
 </div>
```

app-component.ts

```js
 @Component({ selector: "app-root", templateUrl: "app.component.html" })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   isDarkTheme: Observable<boolean>;

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.isDarkTheme = this.themeService.isDarkTheme;
   }

   constructor(
     private themeService: ThemeService
   ) {}
 }
```

theme.service.ts

```js
 @Injectable({
   providedIn: "root"
 })
 export class ThemeService {
   private _darkTheme = new Subject<boolean>();
   isDarkTheme = this._darkTheme.asObservable();

   setDarkTheme(isDarkTheme: boolean): void {
     this._darkTheme.next(isDarkTheme);
   }
 }
```

settings-component.ts

```js
 export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
   isDarkTheme: Observable<boolean>;

   toggleDarkTheme(checked: boolean) {
     this.themeService.setDarkTheme(checked);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.isDarkTheme = this.themeService.isDarkTheme;
   }
 }
```

settings-component.html

```html
 <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="isDarkTheme | async" (change)="toggleDarkTheme($event.checked)">Dark theme
 </mat-slide-toggle>
```

Settings are called by `<router-outlet>`. If I toggle the slider nothing happens. It won't work. If I implement the exact same things in the `<app-header>` it works because it's a child. How to fix this? Do I need a service for nodes of `<router-outlet>`

Comment: This should still work since the value of `isDarkTheme` is centralized in `ThemeService`. In `app-component.ts`, after the first line the `ngOnInit`, do `this.isDarkTheme.subscribe(theme => console.log(theme))` and go to settings to turn in on and see what the value of the log is. It should be true.

Comment: If I just add the line you mentioned I end up in Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined. Otherwise nothing changes at all. I am also a bit wondering

Comment: Why is it undefined? It seems like maybe `ThemeService` is not being injected correctly. Instead of `this.isDarkTheme.subscribe`, try `this.themeService.isDarkTheme.subscribe(darkTheme => console.log(darkTheme));`.

Comment: No matter if the method you mentioned before or the new one the console.log is never called. Thats what I mean. If you look at my code it works fine If i just copy it into the app-header component which is a clear child. Then it works instantly even without subscribing.

Comment: Gosh I fixed it... Through the console.log of the service I've seen that the settings component import was wrong. It was imported with the ending of .js and that was why it did not work. Why ever that happend... Now it works. I still thank you!